# Formatting a Countdown Timer When Timer Reaches Negative Numbers

Tags: swift

I have an Int, this Int relates to number of minutes. I convert this Int to hours, minutes and seconds using following code and all works great until the timer is below 0.

```
let hours = Int(timeRemaining) / 3600
let minutes = Int(timeRemaining) / 60 % 60
let seconds = Int(timeRemaining) % 60
timeLeftLabel.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

The output from the above code looks something like this and it counts down perfectly:
02:56:07

However, as soon as the time reaches 0 the format starts looking like this:
-2:-56:-7 (this is obviously after minus 2 hours, it doesn't immediately jump to minus 2 hours, I'm just trying to highlight the point)

As you can see, there are numerous issues here, firstly the minus symbol, I simply want there to be one minus symbol at the start. Then the 0's are missing from hours and seconds, it should simply read:
-02:56:07

The only way I can think to try and resolve this is to use: replacingOccurrences(of) but was wondering if there was a better option?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better solution is to use a `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
```

Example

```
let timeRemaining: TimeInterval = 2 * 60 * 60 + 56 * 60 + 7
let negative = -1 * timeRemaining
print(formatter.string(from: timeRemaining)!)
print(formatter.string(from: negative)!)
```

> 02:56:07
> -02:56:07

Comment: Thanks Joakim, this works great. The only thing that wasn't showing was the minus symbol. Other than that all the formatting was great. My countdown timer changes color based on time remaining (above 10 mins = .white) (below 10 mins = .orange) (below 0 mins = .red). The colors work perfectly but do you have any ideas why the minus symbol might not be appearing?

Comment: No idea, it was visible for me

Comment: No problem Joakim, I'm going to mark yours as it answered the formatting issue....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want a single negative sign in front of the whole string, start with the *absolute value* of your interval and do your arithmetic, and then prepend the minus sign if the original was negative.

(But I agree that it is better to use a formatter and no arithmetic.)